# Facebook authentication using Oauth 2.0

Tags: facebook, oauth

I want to access facebook REST API's using PHP OAUTH functions instead using their php_sdk. Is there anyone to help me out in this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the REST API? Facebook are phasing it out in favor of the new graph api and oauth2.0 stuff. If you want to use that straight from php (without using the php sdk) I can maybe help. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user details in a table as mentioned in http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/ and manage sessions from that point effectively to achieve your goal